# create special dynamic datagrid from database

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagrid

I am writing a  time table program for our univercity (Smart half or Semi-automatic or etc ) .

I am writing this whit C# And Access Databse .

i have a database with below tables :
 1-teachers (teacher_id,teacher_name)
 2- classes (class_id,class_name)
 3- lessons (lesson_id,lesson_name)
 4-terms (term_id,term_name)
 5- hours (hour_id,hour_name)
 6-days (day_id,day_name)
 7-timetable (time_table_id,teacher_id,lesson_id,term_id,class_id_hour_id,day_id)

I wrote Crud code for all tables exclude time table

i think best thing for this action is datagrid

Now for time table form i want a user friendly UI like below

www.uplooder.net/img/image/47/16197657f8466c5a1b8716aee14d768b/csharp.jpg

I want in the column header (exclude column top right) display hours

And in row (exclude top right) display classes

And in Intersection of any class and hour set teacher and lesson

Notes:

1-first row of datagrid is hours that get from DB
2-first column(from right to left) of datagrid is classes that get from DB
3-if Previously set any cell show teacher name and lesson name

How do i this ?

Please help me

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

i do this

thanks my friends for your answers

timtable form all codes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Time_Table
{
    public partial class timetable : Form
    {
        public timetable()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void FillDataGrid()
        {
            string term_id = this.comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string day_id = this.comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string hour_id;
            string class_id;

            string query;

            DataTable result;

            for (int rowcounter = 0; rowcounter < this.dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count; rowcounter++)
            {
                for (int columncounter = 1; columncounter < this.dataGridViewX1.Columns.Count; columncounter++)
                {
                    class_id = this.dataGridViewX1.Rows[rowcounter].Cells[0].Tag.ToString();
                    hour_id = this.dataGridViewX1.Columns[columncounter].Name;

                    query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE time_table_term_id={0} " +
                        "AND time_table_day_id={1} AND time_table_hour_id={2} AND time_table_class_id={3}", term_id, day_id, hour_id, class_id);

                    result = CrudClass.SelectAll(query, "timetable");

                    if (result.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        query = string.Format("SELECT teacher_name,lesson_name FROM timetable,teachers,lessons WHERE time_table_term_id={0} " +
                        "AND time_table_day_id={1} AND time_table_hour_id={2} AND time_table_class_id={3} AND time_table_teacher_id = teacher_id AND time_table_lesson_id=lesson_id"
                        , term_id, day_id, hour_id, class_id);

                        result = CrudClass.SelectByQuery(query);

                        this.dataGridViewX1.Rows[rowcounter].Cells[columncounter].Value = result.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString() + " / "
                                                                                          + result.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();

                        this.dataGridViewX1.Rows[rowcounter].Cells[columncounter].Style.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
                    }
                    else {
                        this.dataGridViewX1.Rows[rowcounter].Cells[columncounter].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }

                }
            }
        }


        private void timetable_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable ClassNames ;
            DataTable HourNames ;

            ClassNames = CrudClass.SelectAll("SELECT * FROM classes", "classes");
            HourNames = CrudClass.SelectAll("SELECT * FROM hours", "hours");


            this.dataGridViewX1.Columns.Add("empty", "ساعت/نام کلاس");

            for (int i = 0; i < HourNames.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridViewX1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { Name=HourNames.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(),HeaderText=HourNames.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString() });
            }


            for (int classCounter = 0; classCounter < ClassNames.Rows.Count; classCounter++)
            {
                this.dataGridViewX1.Rows.Add(new object[]{ClassNames.Rows[classCounter].ItemArray[2].ToString()});
                this.dataGridViewX1.Rows[classCounter].Cells[0].Tag = ClassNames.Rows[classCounter].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            }


            //------------------------ fill combobox ------------------------------

            DataTable termValues = CrudClass.SelectAll("SELECT * FROM terms","terms");
            DataTable dayValues = CrudClass.SelectAll("SELECT * FROM days", "days");

            this.comboBox1.DataSource = termValues;
            this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "term_name";
            this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "term_id";


            this.comboBox2.DataSource = dayValues;
            this.comboBox2.DisplayMember = "day_name";
            this.comboBox2.ValueMember = "day_id";


        }

        private void dataGridViewX1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridViewX1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            if (comboBox1.Items.Count>0 && comboBox2.Items.Count>0 && dataGridViewX1.Columns.Count>1 && dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count>0 

                && e.ColumnIndex >0 && e.RowIndex>=0 )
            {
                add_timetable frm_add_timetable = new add_timetable();
                frm_add_timetable.term_id = this.comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
                frm_add_timetable.day_id = this.comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
                frm_add_timetable.hour_id = this.dataGridViewX1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
                frm_add_timetable.class_id = this.dataGridViewX1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Tag.ToString();
                frm_add_timetable.ShowDialog();
            }





        }

        private void dataGridViewX1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillDataGrid();
        }

        private void timetable_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillDataGrid();
        }
    }
}
```